# Optimization: Remove difference between list of list

Tags: python, list, optimization

I need to know if i can optimize my code, because i feel like it can be.

Here the context:

```
list1 = [[1,'name1'], [2,'name2'], [3,'name3']]
list2 = [2,3]
for item in list1:
    if item[0] not in list2:
         list1.remove(item)
```

To get list1 i'm doing this:

```
list(filter(lambda x: name in x[1].lower(), list_of_items))
```

So i'm asking if it is really possible to optimize this code ?

**Update:**

As ask i can't use directly list2 in the lmbda filter because i'm getiing it with:

```
list2 = set(item[0] for item in list1) - set(object.id for object in list_in_my_bdd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension instead and only include sub-lists of `list1` whose first element is in `list2`:

```
[item for item in list1 if item[0] in list2]
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks very much like a job for a dictionary lookup which probably is faster than a O(N^2) list comparison. So if you want to have all entries of `list1` whose keys are contained in `list2` and can assume that the keys in `list_of_items` are unique you can do:

```py
list1 = [[1,'name1'], [2,'name2'], [3,'name3']]
dict1 = dict(list1)

list2 = [2,3]
result = [dict1[k] for k in list2]
```

This requires all keys contained in list 2 to actually be in list1 though. Otherwise there will be `None` values inside `result`

### **Timing:**

To reproduce the timings in a notebook:

```py
import numpy as np

list1 = [[i, f"name{i}"] for i in range(10000)]
list2 = np.random.choice(range(10000), 1000).tolist()

dict1 = dict(list1)

%timeit [dict1.get(k) for k in list2]
%timeit [item for item in list1 if item[0] in list2]

>>>10000 loops, best of 5: 141 µs per loop
>>>10 loops, best of 5: 160 ms per loop
```

So the dictionary lookup is approximately 1000 times faster than the list comprehension.

As @Paul mention this is only faster if the setup of `list1` can be replaced by directly using a dictionary:

```py
import numpy as np
list_of_items = [(j, f"name{i}") for j, i in enumerate(np.random.randint(0, 50000, 10000))]
list1 = list(filter(lambda x: "name" in x[1].lower(), list_of_items))
dict1 = dict(filter(lambda x: "name" in x[1].lower(), list_of_items))
```

Comment: I like this answer. It's still worth noting that this requires the numeric values in `list1` to be unique. Also, I guess you are correct with your performance improvement. As I see it, at least in theory your solution would be `O(n)` in contrast to `O(n^2)` in the original approach.

Comment: In this case, casting to dict and then filtering it is actually slower than the list comprehension: 368 ns ± 5.83 ns per loop for the dictionary approach, 287 ns ± 1.38 ns per loop for the list comprehension

Comment: Thanks for the hint Paul. I was implictly assuming that the data in `list1` could be represented in a dictionary directly without taking the detour via a list

Answer (score 0):

what about a list comprehension and set?

```
list1 = [[1,'name1'], [2,'name2'], [3,'name3']]
good = {2,3}

print([[a,b] for a,b in list1 if a in good])
# [[2, 'name2'], [3, 'name3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Note that the variable names are the same as in your question but list2 is actually a set (for efficiency).

```
list1 = [[1,'name1'], [2,'name2'], [3,'name3']]
list2 = {2, 3}
list3 = [item for item in list1 if item[0] in list2]
print(list3)
```

Comment: @Glauco beat me by 20 seconds but I'll leave it here anyway

Answer (score 0):

> To get list1 i'm doing this:

```
list(filter(lambda x: name in x[1].lower(), list_of_items))
```

Why don't you also include the check here:

```py
list(filter(lambda x: name in x[1].lower() and x[0] in list2, list_of_items))
```

Comment: I updating my post to answer you, but in short i'm using the value of list1 to get list2